# Como abrir Fancybox acima do menu

Tags: css, fancybox

Estou com uma dificuldade, ao abrir um `lightbox Fancybox` o mesmo está ficando abaixo de meu menu, alterei a posição do mesmo, mas não gostei do resultado, pois ficou estranho, mas não consegui deixa-lo abrindo acima.

A página com o efeito é essa:
[Página com Lightbox](http://www.ancestofados.com.br/anc/detalhes.php?prod=11)

Eu tentei alterar a abertura do mesmo pelo `z-index`, mas sem sucesso:

```
.fancybox-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10020;
    margin-top:35px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema que tinha, alterei os seguintes arquivos:

style.css

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    // ALTEREI AQUI
    z-index: 1000;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    /*outline: #00FF00 dotted thick;*/
}
```

jquery.fancybox.css

```
.fancybox-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    // ALTEREI AQUI
    z-index: 1000000;
    margin-top:35px;
}
```

Comment: Cuidado com o uso do z-index, chutar um numero alto é tao ruim quanto usar !important no css. use com responsabilidade.